# Using sumo's RealisticEngineModel

Tags: veins, sumo, plexe

I figured out that the realistic engine model from plexe (https://github.com/michele-segata/plexe-sumo) was recently integrated into sumo's main code base. My question is: How can I use the model and specify my own engine parameters. Does the engine model have any influence on the vehicle’s emissions? How can I retrieve engine parameters (rpm and gear) via traci?

Comment: Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". We appreciate that you might be new, but we do expect evidence of the effort you've put into this. Where did you search? Why didn't it help? If it did, where is the code you wrote to test what you learned? If you didn't write code, why not? If you did, what is the minimal code that demonstrates the problem you encountered, along with the explanation of the problem, and the minimal input data and the expected result? Without that it's hard to help you.